# Returning a hashmap in a method with Optional return type

Tags: java, hashmap, return, option-type

I spent a lot of time crafting this code to assign a certain slot-value using a HashMap (the code works as intended, when I tested it outside this method), based on my assignments instructions. However I just noticed, that the method that I have to implement this code in, is an Optional (the method itself can't be modified, but I could add other methods).

Now if I add an order by calling `addAnOrder` my entire code gets ignored, because I don't know how to actually return the newly added values for the `HashMap slots` that I create with every added order. So for each order I add, I begin with a completely empty HashMap.

Is my entire code useless now, because I have overseen this detail? The instructions state, that my return value of this method has to be the `int givenSlot`, but how do I add the new values for my HashMap, so they actually get taken into consideration when calculating the slot value?

```
public Optional<Integer> addAnOrder(Order order, int preferredSlot) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> slots = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int givenSlot = 0, count = 0;

        if (currentDate.equals(date)) {
            if (slots.size() < (numberOfTimeSlots + 1) * (capacityPerSlot + 1)) {
                if (!slots.containsValue(preferredSlot)) {
                    givenSlot = preferredSlot;
                    slots.put(count, preferredSlot);
                    count++;
                } else {
                    int valueCount = 0;
                    for (Integer value : slots.values()) {
                        if (value.equals(preferredSlot)) {
                            valueCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (valueCount <= capacityPerSlot) {
                        givenSlot = preferredSlot;
                        slots.put(count, preferredSlot);
                        count++;

                    } else {
                        int valuePlus = 0, valueMinus = 0, valueCount2 = 0, valueCount3 = 0, i = 1, j = 1;
                        boolean plus = false, minus = false;

                        for (int a = 1; preferredSlot + i < numberOfTimeSlots + 1; i++) {
                            valueCount2 = 0;
                            for (Integer value : slots.values()) {
                                if (value.equals(preferredSlot + i)) {
                                    valueCount2++;
                                    if (valueCount2 > capacityPerSlot) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (valueCount2 <= capacityPerSlot) {
                                valuePlus = preferredSlot + i;
                                if (valueCount2 <= capacityPerSlot) {
                                    plus = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        for (int b = 1; preferredSlot - j > -2; j++) {
                            valueCount3 = 0;
                            for (Integer value2 : slots.values()) {
                                if (value2.equals(preferredSlot - j)) {
                                    valueCount3++;
                                    if (valueCount3 > capacityPerSlot) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (valueCount3 <= capacityPerSlot) {
                                valueMinus = preferredSlot - j;
                                if (valueCount3 <= capacityPerSlot) {
                                    minus = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (plus == true && minus == true) {
                            if (Math.abs(preferredSlot - valuePlus) < Math.abs(preferredSlot - valueMinus)) {
                                givenSlot = preferredSlot + i;
                                slots.put(count, preferredSlot + i);
                                count++;
                                plus = false;
                                minus = false;
                            } else if (valueMinus >= 0) {
                                givenSlot = preferredSlot - j;
                                slots.put(count, preferredSlot - j);
                                count++;
                                plus = false;
                                minus = false;
                            } else {
                                givenSlot = preferredSlot + i;
                                slots.put(count, preferredSlot + i);
                                count++;
                                plus = false;
                                minus = false;
                            }
                        } else if (plus == true && minus == false) {
                            givenSlot = preferredSlot + i;
                            slots.put(count, preferredSlot + i);
                            count++;
                            plus = false;
                        } else if (minus == true && plus == false && valueMinus >= 0) {
                            givenSlot = preferredSlot - j;
                            slots.put(count, preferredSlot - j);
                            count++;
                            minus = false;
                        } else {
                            return Optional.empty();
                        }
                        return Optional.of(givenSlot);
                    }
                    return Optional.of(givenSlot);
                }
                return Optional.of(givenSlot);
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add getSlotsMap() method to retrieve the map, which you will have initialized some where in application initialization code.

```
public Optional<Integer> addAnOrder(Order order, int preferredSlot){
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> slots = getSlotsMap();
    //do your thing
    return Optional.empty();
}
public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getSlotsMap(){
    //add logic to get the map from some object
    return null;
}
```

Edit: modified the answer as per OP author's input.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the method declaration, only to add new methods to call inside of this method.

Comment: What do you mean by do your thing?

Comment: I meant put the whole logic that you've mentioned in the question. I did not want to paste the whole method.